# Exibir código formatado em html do banco em uma página Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá. Estou construindo um blog em Javascript com o Next JS e gravando o conteudo do post no Firebase.
Gostaria de saber se há alguma função no javascript para que quando retornasse o conteúdo do post com tags html mescladas ao mesmo, ele exibisse o texto formatado. Exemplo:

Isto é um parágrafo

ao invés de

```
<p>Isto é um parágrafo</p>
```

Este é o trecho onde exibo o conteudo que viria formatado:

```
<div className="column is-9">
   <div className="is-size-6">
     {content}
   </div>
   <br />
</div>
```

Comment: como você tá dando a saida no javascript? Ambas as maneiras são possíveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está mostrando uma `string` contendo tags, ao invés de código `html` de verdade.

```
//O seu content está vindo algo assim:

'<p>Isto é um parágrafo</p>'
```

Desta forma o javascript entende que o dado é uma `string` e mostra ela como está, sem interpretar as tags. Uma solução seria usar o `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` ficaria assim o código:

```
<div className="column is-9">

<div className="is-size-6" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}>

 </div>
 <br />
</div>
```

assim ele injeta sua `string` na div escapando as tags `html`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Eliton, era exatamente isso o que eu precisava, funcionou certinho. Obrigado mesmo!